# Strategy for tackling $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(\ln n)^{-p}}.$

Tags: limits

Can someone explain me the strategy for calculating this limit and other limit like this?$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(\ln n)^{-p}}.$$

I have tried with the squeeze rule, l'Hopital and other simple strategies without success.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your $p$?

Comment: @ploosu $p$ is a fixed real number. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[L'Hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) will get you there.

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n}{(\ln{n})^{-p}}} &= \lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}} \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)}} \\
\end{align}
$$

For $p\lt 0$, the power in the denominator is positive. This means we get:
$$
f'(n) = 1\\
g'(n) = (-p)*(\ln{n})^{-p-1}*\frac{1}{n}
$$
Simplifying our equation:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n}{(\ln{n})^{-p}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n}{-p(\ln{n})^{-p-1}}} \\
$$
This can be continued until the power in the denominator is zero, leaving only a constant value $C$. Therefore:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n}{(\ln{n})^{-p}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n}{C}} = \infty \\
$$

For $p>0$, the power in the denominator will be negative. This simplifies our equation to:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n}{(\ln{n})^{-p}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}{n(\ln{n})^{p}} = \infty \\
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\log^{-p}n}=\infty\;,\;\;\forall\,p\in\Bbb R$$

You can show the above by cases: for $\;p\ge 0\;$ it's trivial since the product of sequences diverging to infinity diverges to infinity, and for $\;p<0\;$ you can prove it by means of l'Hospital's rule ($\;[k]+1\;$ times) and the function

$$\frac x{\log^kx}\;,\;\;k>0$$

Comment: @AlexR No, technically the above covers all the cases. l'H's rule is only for the case $\;p<0\;$ , the other case being trivial, as pointed out there.

Comment: Okay I see that you have to use
$$\frac n{\log^{-p} n} = \frac n{\log^{\lceil p \rceil} n} \cdot \frac n{\log^{-p-\lceil p \rceil} n}$$
To complete it for any $p$. I suggest you add that as a remark.

Comment: @AlexR, I think you're really confussing things here: I don't need any $\;p\;$ in my last line. I just used $\;k>0\;$ ...who cares how we call constants/variables? Oh, I see...because of the k times thing? Well, that's a little...well, I shall edit. Thanks.

Comment: That was exactly my point. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the $p$ doesn't even matter. If it's positive you have $n(\ln n)^p$ which clearly goes to infinity as $n \to \infty$. If it's negative you still have the $n$ upstairs and $n$ grows much faster than $(\ln n)^{-p}$.

Make the substitution $s = \ln n$. It is equivalent to consider this subsituted version when $s \to \infty$.

You have $n = e^s$ and the function you are considering becomes

$\frac{e^s}{s^{-p}}$

Are you familiar with this sort of function as $s \to \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Case I. $p\ge 0$. Then
$$
\frac{n}{(\ln n)^{-p}}=n(\ln n)^{p}>n,
$$
and as $n\to\infty$, so does $\frac{n}{(\ln n)^{-p}}$.

Case II. $p<0.$ Then for $q=-p>0$, let
$$
f(x)=x(\ln x)^q. 
$$
Clearly, 
$$
f'(x)=(\ln x)^q+qx(\ln x)^{p-1}\ge q\mathrm{e}, \quad \text{for}\quad x\ge \mathrm{e},
$$
and thus
$$
f(x)=f(\mathrm{e})+\int_{\mathrm{e}}^x f'(t)\,dt\ge \,f(\mathrm{e})+(x-\mathrm{e})q\mathrm{e}
\to \infty,
$$
as $x\to\infty$.